# Differentiation by the integrand

Tags: calculus

So, when rereading the proof of differentiation under the integral sign and trying to derive the proof using only chain rule (in particular, to generate the $\int \frac{\partial}{\partial}$ term just before Dominant Convergence Theorem is applied to switch the limits), I stumbled upon the following weird differentiation and trying to make sense of it.

$$\frac{d}{df} \int f(x)dx$$

For simplicity of the investigation, I choose $f(x)=e^x$ as it is a nice function

$$\frac{d}{de^x}\int e^x dx$$

**Pathway 0: Direct integration**

$$\frac{d}{d e^x} \int e^x dx = \frac{d(e^x + C)}{d e^x} = 1$$

**Pathway 1: Using Chain Rule**

$$\frac{d}{d e^x} \int e^x dx = \frac{d x}{de^x} \frac{d}{dx} \int e^x dx = \frac{d (\ln e^x)}{de^x} e^x = \frac{1}{e^x}e^x = 1$$

**Pathway 2: By first principles**

$$\frac{d}{d e^x} \int e^x dx = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{\int (e+h)^x-e^x dx}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{\int (h^x-1)e^x dx}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{h^x- e^x \ln h}{h \ln h} + C = \text{Blow up to minus infinity}$$

> 1. Why is it so? How to recoincile Pathway 2 with the outcome of Pathways 0 and 1?
> 2. Is $\frac{d}{df} \int f(x)dx$ actually a special case of a functional derivative?

Comment: Your "By first principles" is differentiating with respect to $e$, not $e^x$. You should've had $\int (e^x + h)dx - \int e^xdx$ in the numerator.